# js. Compact passing of props from object to object

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

```
let source = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4 };

let dest = { one: source.one, two: "alterTwo", threeish: source.three}; 
          // threeish: get with different name. four is not wanted in dest

dest.five = source.five!==undefined ? source.five : 5;   
            //A default value on dest.five
```

How can this logic be compacted in an "object destructuring fashion"? a clean single line is possible?

Comment: ... just deep (or not deep) copy it? And do the necessary modifications?

Comment: @Rajesh ... compact as in clean code. To make it 1-line, just remove all newlines and replace them with semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

Note: You can also use `five || 5` but it will fail for `0`. So kept ternary operator.

```js
let source = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4 };

const { one, three: threeish, five } = source

let dest = {
  one,
  two: "alterTwo",
  threeish,
  five: (five !== undefined ? five : 5)
};

console.log(dest)
```

#### Reference:

- [Object destructuring - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Answer (score 1):

```
let source = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4 };
let {one, two, three: threeish, four, five} = source;
let dest = {
  one,
  two: 'alterTwo',
  threeish,
  five: five !== 'undefined'? five : 5
};
```

I don't really think that you can compact too much. Just pay attention that  "object destructuring fashion" it's not always good. Just write simple code, easy to read and understand, even if it takes more lines of code. Writing sophisticated code doesn't help at all.

Comment: Note, you do not need `two` and `four` in object destructuring.